# spacing (margins?) between divs

Tags: html, css, default, margin

http://test.recollectedtime.com

There are these default margins between my divs. I want them to be flush.

I've tried a universal selector,

```
* {
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

and I'm using a reset.css.

I don't understand why the margins appear.

Any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: Do not use `!important` to solve this kind of problem. Use a selector with the same specificity but written after the one you want to override (the last instruction with the same selector specificity wins) OR use a selector with more specificity. `!important` will cause a bunch of problems later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see it for yourself easily:

In Chrome, right click on the element and choose "inspect" to open the dev-tools.
In the bottom right pane, choose the tab "computed style".
locate the margin properties, and click on the right arrow to see the details. you will see this:

[image: dev tools property detail]

You can see that the 152 px data comes from "header auto" in line 35 of the style.CSS.
And that is a link, so you can go directly to the line.

Comment: Thanks for that, didn't realise you could isolate exactly where attributes are from. Very useful!

Answer (score 0):

You have applied 100px margin in the style.css file.

Take a look at line 38.

```
/* START HEADER--------------------  */

header {
    margin: 100px auto;     <------Here

    width: 960px;
    background-color:purple;
    font-size: 20pt;


}
```